# AWS CDK Glue Job + Trigger created but won't run

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, aws-cdk

I have the following AWS CDK configuration in TypeScript (abriged):

```
const jobProps = {
  command: {
    name: 'glueetl',
    pythonVersion: '3',
    scriptLocation: `s3://${s3bucket.bucketName}/${this.scriptName}`,
  },
  connections: { connections: [connectionName] },

  defaultArguments: { },
  description: idEnv + '-job',
  executionProperty: {
    maxConcurrentRuns: 1,
  },
  glueVersion: '2.0',
  maxRetries: 0,
  name: idEnv + '-job',
  numberOfWorkers: 2,
  role: glueServiceRole.roleArn,
  timeout: 180, // minutes
  workerType: 'Standard',
};
const job = new CfnJob(this, idEnv, jobProps);


const trigger = new CfnTrigger(this, idEnv + '-trigger', {
  type: 'SCHEDULED',
  description: 'Scheduled run for ' + job.name,
  schedule: this.JOB_SCHEDULE,
  actions: [
    {
      jobName: job.name,
    },

  ],
});
```

The trigger is created, it is seen in the Console and it is linked to the Job. But it just won't run (manual Job run is OK). What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add "startOnCreation: true" to the CfnTrigger props, so the trigger status will be enabled by default.